# MYSQL - Actualizar campo correlativo de una misma tabla segun codigo

Tags: mysql, update

Quisiera actualizar el campo de una tabla mediante un correlativo (char) que se reinice cada vez que el codigo del registro cambie.

Lo que he podido conseguir, es generar una consulta que genera el correlativo por cada codigo pero no he podido adaptarlo a la sentencia UPDATE.

Tengo esta tabla como ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE log_guias_detalles (scodigo Char(05), sguia_detalle_item Char(02));

INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0001', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0001', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0001', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0002', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0002', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0002', '');
INSERT INTO log_guias_detalles VALUES ('A0003', '');
```

Aquí realizando la consulta y viendo el campo sguia_detalle_item en blanco.

```
SELECT * FROM log_guias_detalles;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y con esta consulta obtengo este resultado que deseo pero no puedo aún colocarlo en un UPDATE

```
SELECT  @ncontador := CASE WHEN @scodigo = scodigo THEN LPAD(@ncontador + 1, 2, '0') ELSE @ncontador := '01' END AS sguia_detalle_item,
        @scodigo := scodigo AS scodigo
FROM log_guias_detalles
ORDER BY scodigo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan apoyar como aplicarlo en un UPDATE.

Saludos a todos.

Comment: Me parece que deberías determinar cuando realizaras dicha acción,: si la realizaras cada vez que se ingrese un registro o cuando cambie un registro, me parece que cambiar todos lo registros de la tabla cada vez que se ingrese uno es poco practico ya que la base podría crecer mucho y dicha acción podría alterar el funcionamiento, en todo caso para lo que requieres están los Triggers los cuales los puedes crear para que disparen una acción cada vez que se ingrese un nuevo registro y pueden ser BEFORE INSERT , AFTER INSERT y varios mas.